# Cakephp2 post to plugin controller

Tags: forms, cakephp, plugins, controller

Having hard time figuring out how to post a form to a plugin controller.

Say I have a reg/login plugin that could be shared with different apps.

in reg.ctp:

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url'=>array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'submit','plugin'=>'user')));
```

I get missing controller.. in app/controller/user.php

what did do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your controller is not pluralised. All controllers in Cake, by convention, are plurals.

```
array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'submit', 'plugin' => 'user');
```

Should route to

```
app/Plugin/User/Controller/UsersController::submit()
```